# Problems with Paypal SDK integration

Tags: ios, paypal

I have a problem with PayPal integration in iOS.  When I return to place the code for payment, I get an error:

[Linked Command failed with exit code 1 (user -v to see invocation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vNDp.png)

Answer (score 2):

you need to install the pods for pay pal

go to your paypal demo app folder 
open the podfile add the following

platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK'

save then
type pod install on terminal
you problem will be solve for better information 
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK